# Flutter Validate DropDownButton without using DropDownButtonFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Im trying to use a dropDownButton instead of a dropDownButtonFormField because i run thru alot of bugs that i see in the dropDownButtonFormField widget. One problem is that in dropDownButtonFormField the clickable area to open the items is only over the hint text and not a cm under it, witch in my case created bad ux. The second problem is that in the dropDownButtonFormField, if an item is a long text and the user presses it when it displays on the main part of the dropdown, the text doesnt create a new line so the user can see the text, the same thing doesnt happen to the dropDownButton widget. Im using dropDownButtonFormField only to use the validator. This is with using DropDownButton Widget. [image]

And this is using the dropDownButtonFormField Widget while having a long text.
[image]

```
Center locationDropDown() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please select a location';
            }
            return null;
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          ),
          value: chooseLocation,
          hint: const Text('Select a location'),
          isExpanded: true,
          items: workingData!.map((some) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(
                some.name + ' (${some.location})',
              ),
              value: some.id,
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? displayedValue) {
            setState(
              () {
                chooseLocation = displayedValue!;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isDense: false,
```

Add **isDense** value **false** in **DropdownButtonFormField**.